# Find a basis for the space of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Question: Find a basis for the space of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

Take, $n=2$. Any matrix can be written in the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix}$, where $a,b,c\in F$, where $F$ is a field.

Now $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

It is easy to see that $a\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, then we can only get $a=b=c=0$.

Hence the basis is: $\mathbf{B}=\Big\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\Big\}$

I think, the general case is inductive.

Is this okay? Or, this does not imply that $\mathbf{B}$ should be basis.

Also, I know that basis is not unique. So, if this is okay, then what are the other way we can represent basis element (I am just stuck in that one answer actually!)

Comment: If you let $E_{ij}$ to be the matrix with a $1$ in the $(i,j)$-entry and zero everywhere else, then you can write $\textbf{B}=\{ E_{11}, E_{12}+ E_{21}, E_{22}\}$. In the general $n\times n$ setting, $\textbf{B}=\{ E_{ii}, E_{jk}+ E_{kj}: 1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j< k\leq n \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. The first half of your proof shows that $B$ spans the symmetric matrices and the second half shows that $B$ is linearly independent; thus, it is a basis. I would not call the proof of this in higher dimensions inductive *per se*, as (the proof I would write, anyways), doesn't rely on anything we've proved about smaller dimensions to prove things about larger dimensions. However, you are right that the proof is analogous.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and thanks for the clarification for. it would be "proof is analogous" rather than "proof is inductive".